# XDEBUG (somehow) affects cross-origin headers

Tags: php, cors, cross-domain, xdebug, lumen

Here's what i've done:

- created fresh lumen project via composer
- installed & configured jwt-auth and jwt-auth-guard
- installed laravel-cors and configured it for lumen according to docs

Now, the thing is it's working - but only when xdebug is enabled in php.ini. When xdebug is disabled, however, cors headers don't work.

To be specific. When xdebug is disabled cors headers are working only for OPTIONS preflight and for GET methods. When xdebug is enabled everything works just perfect.

I've tested few other cors libraries too, and the behaviour is consistent. Xdebug enabled = cors headers present as they should. Xdebug disabled = `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.xxx.dev/v1/authentication/login. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.`.

Of course i could live with xdebug enabled, but it's really annoying as it slows down PHP more than 10 times (at least on windows), so i tend to disable it when i'm working on fronend js client.

Environment: Windows 10, Wampserver, Apache 2.4.18, PHP 5.6.19

Comment: How about sending the header manually (e.g. set the directive in a .htaccess)? But it's strange that Xdebug sends CORS headers.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois of course it works when defined in .htaccess as it bypass PHP entirely, but it's very possible that i might need per route cors configuration in future, so i will hit the wall anyway - sooner or later - this way. I've also updated the description a bit to be more clear.

Comment: You have to send the header anyway, that Xdebug sends a CORS header is strange and isn't supposed to happen. So **you** have to send the header anyway, either per route-basis in your php file or for all routes by .htaccess, it doesn't matter in the end.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois `either per route-basis` is exactly what i'm trying to do! But it's not that Xdebug is sending CORS, it's that the headers *are* sent *only* when Xdebug happen to be enabled. I can step through the code how the library sets & sends all the headers and it works. But once i comment out Xdebug in php.ini there's no CORS headers any more. Any way i can see that this is something extremly strange and i'm probably better of overriding it in .htaccess just for local development as you suggest, however that's not a happy news really.

Comment: I'm quite confused now. Do you actually try to send the CORS header in your php file but when Xdebug is disabled, then you don't see the CORS header in the HTTP response? And if you enable Xdebug, then you have the CORS header in the HTTP response? If that is the case, then you maybe want to seek help from the Xdebug devs directly. https://xdebug.org/support.php

Comment: @CharlotteDunois yes, that's correct: CORS headers are present in the response *only* when Xdebug is *enabled*. That's why it's so strange. I don't know how Xdebug devs could know why something that should work on vanilla php is not working, while it is working only when Xdebug is enabled, but i'll try to ping them.